# Accessing drop down from google registration page using Selenium

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am accessing following link using selenium + firefox browser

https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&hl=en&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Den-ha-apac-in-bk-refresh13&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-apac-in-bk-refresh13&utm_medium=ha

`driver.get(baseUrl);` where baseUrl is above url.

I am trying to select United Kingdom.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Location']")).sendKeys("United");
```

The above code select the first drop down value starting with United.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Location']")).sendKeys("United Kingdom");
```

If i use above code, i.e. insert space between, it does not work as expected.

How can i select United Kingdom.

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

clicking on it directly after clicking on the dropdown should work:

`public void selectLocation(String countryName) {
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Location']")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='goog-menuitem-content' and text()='" + countryName + "']")).click();
   System.out.println("Clicking on option '" + countryName + "' for location.");
}`